# The requested package amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php 3.5.0 is satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php[3.5.0] but these conflicirements or minimum-stability

Tags: php, magento, sdk, composer-php, amazon-pay

I am trying to install Magento 2.3.3 with PHP 7.1.but when I  try to install the composer, i get the error  `The requested package amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php 3.5.0 is satisfiable by amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php[3.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`

Comment: Could you share your composer.json file in your question?

Comment: {
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.3.3",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.3",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "bsscommerce/reindex-data": "^1.0",

Comment: You can edit your question and include it there. That way it's more readable and can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

though your amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php 3.5.0 is satisfiable, you need to update the package to the latest, ie 3.7.o

`composer require amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php 3.7.`0